# customize dock bar in liferay 6.2

Tags: tomcat7, liferay-6, dock

I need to add some buttons in liferay's dock bar and Im not quite sure which jsp file is the one.
I added these buttons in `/html/taglib/aui/nav_item/end.jsp`

**RESULT**: before authentication: dockbar is cool
 [image: DockBar before authentification]
        after authentication: not cool
[image: DockBar befoaftere authentification]
liferay-version: liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2
tomcat-version: tomcat-7.0.42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok to add somthg in liferay6.2 dockbar
The files to edit: 
  - /html/portlet/dockbar/view_admin/links.jspf (after authentification )
  - /html/portlet/dockbar/vew_user_account.portal.jspf (before authentification )

Good luck every one.
If more help needed , my mail : mlle.haji@gmail.om

Answer (score 0):

> Ok to add somthg in liferay6.2 dockbar The files to edit: - >/html/portlet/dockbar/view_admin/links.jspf (befor authentification ) - >/html/portlet/dockbar/vew_user_account.portal.jspf (after authentification )

Actually, it is the other way around :) For after authentication the file you need to edit is view_admin_links.jspf in /html/portlet/dockbar

And for before authentication, it is view_user_account.portal.jspf

Hope it helps